# PHP ECHO to JSON result = JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have echo from php = `echo "{success: true, redirect: '/home', auth_key:'$auth_key'}";`

and tried to parse it but encountering error =

> JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the
>   JSON data

I tried jquery parse and normal json.parse method

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/login/process",
    data: user,
    success: function (response) {
            var resp = $.parseJSON(response);
    }
});
```

I would like to get the value of auth from the echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. Try it on [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/). If you scroll down the page you will see *Common errors* and a rule:

> Enclosing your collection keys in quotes. Proper format for a collection is { "key": "value" }

It should be:

```
echo '{"success": true, "redirect": "/home", "auth_key":"$auth_key"}';
```

Javascript test:

```js
let invalidJson = "{success: true, redirect: '/home', auth_key:'$auth_key'}",
    validJson = '{"success": true, "redirect": "/home", "auth_key":"$auth_key"}';
    
try {
  console.log("invalid json", JSON.parse(invalidJson));
}
catch (e)
{
  console.error(e);
}
    
try {
  console.log("valid json", JSON.parse(validJson));
}
catch (e)
{
  console.error(e);
}
```

If you are creating a hard code json, I would advise to create an [`Array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and `echo` it with [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). The function will produce a valid json with your data and you won't need to worry about formatting it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you create array and save it as json and check,

```
$a =  ["success" =>  true, "redirect" =>  '/home', "auth_key" => $auth_key];
echo json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);die; //
```

JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES - Don't escape `/`.

**Output**

```
{"success":true,"redirect":"/home","auth_key":"123213123123"}
```

This will give sure short json output.